# Exception: render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template_name'. Why am i getting this exception? haven't came across this before

Tags: python, django, view

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        State_name = request.POST.get('statename', '')
        state = states(State_name=State_name)
        state.save()
```

> The exception is located in the render.
>   **render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template_name'**

```
        return render('report/states.html')
```

Answer (score 5):

The first argument to `render` is the request. The second is the template name. Since you are only passing one argument, Python interprets it as the request.